# gethostbyname() not working

Tags: c, host, gethostbyname

I am trying to find my source's IP yet it won't work.

```
void getSourceIp(struct hostent *sourceHost, struct ip *ipStruct)
{
    char sourceName[100];

    if (gethostname(sourceName,sizeof(sourceName)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error in function gethostname().\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((sourceHost = gethostbyname(sourceName)) == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "The source " << sourceName << " is unknown.\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ipStruct->ip_src = (*(struct in_addr *) sourceHost->h_addr_list);
    std::cout << "IP Address: " << inet_ntoa(ipStruct->ip_src);
}
```

MAIN function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct hostent *sourceHostent       = NULL;
    struct hostent *destinationHostent  = NULL;
    struct ip *ip                       = NULL;

    getSourceIp(sourceHostent,ip);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is "The source macbook is unknown."

Comment: "gethostbyname() not working" - probably it is, but your expectations don't match its behavior.

Comment: what do you mean? @H2CO3

Comment: sorry, I forgot to finish my comment... >.< Silly me.

Comment: No worries. Haha, nicely put, well it sure isn't working because I have checked with the debugger and the sourceHost structure remains NULL after the function call. Am I missing something?

Comment: that doesn't mean that "they are not working". Inspect what kind of error occurred using the `herror()` or `hstrerror()` functions.

Comment: Does it exist a line within `/etc/hosts` with the name "macbook"? Try with a fully qualified name, like macbook.localnet or something like that. Try also with a known hostname, like "stackoverflow.com" and see if it can resolve it.

Comment: the herror is failed: Unknown host. I have checked /etc/hosts and there is no "macbook". What I don't get is why since I got the name using gethostname() function ...

Comment: The name returned by `gethostbyname` is likely not in your DNS. You should look into using `getifaddrs` instead.

Comment: Additionally, you have some bugs in your code. Your `getSourceIp` won't pass the value out through the pointers like you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments on the question, you're method has several issues. The first is that it that the results are not passed back to the calling function. You need to use a double pointer to do this.

Next, the value returned from `gethostbyname` is allocated in static memory, so it can be overwritten the next time you call the function. You need to copy the result into your own memory. This is non-trivial because you need to deep copy it and not just `malloc(sizeof(struct hosting))`. The complexity of doing this is why `gethostbyname` is depreciated. Depending on your target platform, there are much better options to do DNS lookup.

Even if the lookup succeeded in your code, you will get a SEGFAULT. You are passing the value `NULL` for `ipStruct` and then attempting to dereference and write to it. If you dereference a NULL pointer, you're going to have a bad time. You should spend some time to understand memory management in C using `malloc` and `free`.

Without seeing more code, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your `struct ip`. It looks like you're trying to get one or more IP addresses of the host as `char *`, but you've missed that target by a considerable amount. I can offer a bit more help if you can elaborate on the intent.

This last piece is stylistic, but doing assignments in `if` statements is error prone and a generally bad idea. You should get out of the habit of doing it.

Comment: I am trying to implement ping. I have to get the source and destination IP addresses and send some ICMP echo requests. Thank you so much. Oh and I'm using a macbook.

Comment: Why are you implementing Ping? It already exists. Is there something that you are attempting to do differently or is this a learning exercise? If it is a learning exercise, what constraints are on the solution (UI, libraries available, supported platforms, etc)?

Comment: It's my computer network's homework. The available libraries are the C/C++ ones, it should work on my mac for now.

Comment: The final application should be similar to the mtr command in linux yet for now I'm just trying to send some icmp requests. I'm writing in Qt but I'm not allowed to use Qt libraries, not even for the sockets. I will be using raw ones and in the end I will also make a UI for the program.

Comment: If the topic is something that interests you, there is an amazing book by [Stevens](http://www.amazon.com/Unix-Network-Programming-Volume-Networking/dp/0131411551/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1385239333&sr=8-1&keywords=Network+programming+by+stevens).

Comment: To implement PING, you do not need to know your current IP address. You can use `INADDR_ANY` with your `bind`.